# Error setting up react-native-unimodules: Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods, react-native-unimodules

I'm following the expo docs to [install react-native-unimodules](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-unimodules/#configuration-for-ios) in a plain react-native app. However the changes to my Podfile appear to break things when running `pod install`.

Here's the change that seems to be responsible. The first two lines of the Podfile were:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

They're now changed to this:

```
require File.join(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`, "../scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`, "../native_modules")
require File.join(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native-unimodules/package.json')"`, "../cocoapods.rb")
```

Which causes this error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- /[myproject]/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/package.json
/../cocoapods.rb.
```

The file in question does appear to be in the correct location, so I'm not sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by reverting to the previous two lines, and adding:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
```